# Can function pointers be used in python to reduce dependencies between classes?

Tags: python, model-view-controller, interface, function-pointers

So, in languages like Java, in some MVC pattern, it's common to reduce coupling between classes using interfaces.

Is it legitimate in python to use function pointers to achive same thing?

Let's say we have MainFrame that needs only one function of controller, would you change something in code below, and is there some potential problem?

```
class MainFrame(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._listeners = []

    def fireEvent(self):
        for l in self._listeners:
            l()

    def addListener(self, funcPtr):
        self._listeners.append(funcPtr)


class Controller(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def eventRised(self):
        print "controller recived event"

def main():

    m = MainFrame()

    c = Controller()

    m.addListener(c.eventRised)

    m.fireEvent()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The output of program is:

```
controller recived event
```

Comment: yes it's possible. You should be able to do this with slotted inheritance

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfectly legitimate way to write code. This type of method is known as a callback. Note that in Java the pattern of using an interface for something like this is actually a result of its historical limitations in not having function objects. Python does not have that deficiency, so your solution will work.